# Nodewebkit using Sails.js and Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sails.js, node-webkit

I have managed to run Sails in NW environment.
Has anyone managed to use NW+Sails+SQlite?

I am making a prototype application, as a proof of concept. Soon I will try to make an effort to use SQLite. Any idea suggestion is more then welcome.

We managed to run NW+Express+SQlite. But since the application will be huge, using an MVC is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not trivial. First, you will need to use the "sqlite3" NPM package, but there's also an additional step:

You will need to build SQLite into your Node Webkit though, which is well documented on the [SQLite website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3).